# How to select components through the Transform Gizmo?

Tags: modeling

I have Blender installed on 2 PC's. On PC (a) if I go into component mode and have the transform gizmo visible, I can select a vert and then individually select the neighbouring verts through the transform gizmo. The gizmo does not block selections...    on PC (b) however, I cannot do this. It will instead try to trackball rotate the first selected component, even though I am not dragging the mouse, but stationary clicking. The transform gizmo is blocking the selection.

I have compared, by eye, all the preferences etc and they are identical.  Is there an option or a toggle somewhere that would cause this behaviour? being able to select through the gizmo is pretty necessary for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and I changed the vertex selection shortcut, because it was conflicting with the gizmo selection, so go into Preferences > Keymap > Preferences > Select With > Right

Answer (score 0):

In the Keymap Preferences there is the option Activate Gizmo...   this needs to be set to Drag and not Press.

However, it seems there is a bug that can make this entire preferences section disappear from the Ketmap preferences.